# NewID() taking long time to process

Tags: sql, newid

I am executing the code below for a table with 2 million plus records but NewID() is taking a long time to run.

Can you suggest an alternate method to make the query faster?

```
DELETE FROM Table1
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT TOP 60000 ID FROM Table1 
WHERE flag <> '1'
ORDER BY NEWID()) 
AND
ID NOT IN(SELECT ID FROM Table1
WHERE flag = '1');
```

Comment: does your Flag coulum have an index? Provide a create table/  index definitions.

Comment: why you want to order by `NEWID()`

Comment: What are you trying to do with this code? With the TOP 60000 and the ORDER BY NEWID() it's just going to randomly select 60000 IDs. Is that your goal?

Comment: Looks like it is intended to delete all but a randomly selected 60k rows that have flag<>'1'.

Comment: Yes, flag column has an Index.  I am using Newid() to select random  60000 rows from the table where flag <> '1' and rows where flag = '1'. Delete the rest rows.

Comment: Are there any duplicate ID's in the table?

Comment: Yes, there are duplicate ids in the table.

Comment: Hi "NoDisplayName". I am using Newid() to generate random 60000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

How about this... should be twice as fast

```
DELETE FROM Table1
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT TOP 60000 ID FROM Table1 
                 WHERE flag <> '1'
                 ORDER BY NEWID()) 
   AND flag != '1';
```

Comment: I started to suggest the same, but if there are duplicate IDs in the table, with different values for flag, the results will not be the same.